# Display error alert upon form submission

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I want when I submit form if username or password is incorrect, then it should display me alert box. For the alert message I used the alertify plugin, but it is showing traditional alert box. My code is this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert({
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user',
    });
</script>
```

But I want the following output:

[alertmessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cL6.png)

For that i used this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alertify.alert({
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user',
    });
</script>
```

It is not displaying correctly. Please help.

Comment: What you have given doesn't actually work. Does it?

Comment: yes ,it is not working correctly when i am submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](http://alertifyjs.com/alert.html) for the library you are using:

> ```
> alertify.alert(message);
> ```

You are supposed to pass a *string* containing your message, not an object containing a `msg` property which contains that string.

```
alertify.alert('Are you sure you want to delete this user');
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggsted but still it is not working.